# How to run php script from a c program which is called by XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: php, c, xmlhttprequest, cgi, lighttpd

Here is my problem:
on my server there is a php script that sends an email.
My script works fine and I can run it from the command line:

```
$ php5-cgi /var/www/cgi-bin/send_email.php sujet,texte
```

but the php script should be called by another program in c language (alert email if needed ...).

```
int main(){
system("php5-cgi /var/www/cgi-bin/send_email.php sujet,texte");
printf("ok");
return 0;}
```

If I call my c program from the command line:
`$ /var/www/cgi-bin/envoi_email_test` 
thats OK I receive the email.

But if I call my c program using "XMLHttpRequest()" with a button on one of my html page, it does not work.

The "alert(xhr.responseText)" displays:

```
 *8CJ??P\i?? ?????0?`??T?????0? ??/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o$d$a/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.ocall_gmon_start/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crtn.ocrtstuff.c__JCR_LIST____do_global_dtors_auxcompleted.5637__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entryframe_dummy__frame_dummy_init_array_entryenvoi_email_test.celf-init.oS__FRAME_END____JCR_END____init_array_end_DYNAMIC__init_array_start_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE___libc_csu_finidata_startprintf@@GLIBC_2.4__bss_start___bss_end___edata_fini__bss_end____data_start__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.4system@@GLIBC_2.4__gmon_start____dso_handle_IO_stdin_used__libc_csu_init_end_start__end____bss_startmain_Jv_RegisterClassesabort@@GLIBC_2.4_init
```

and other strange text.

I know my c program runs because if I comment out the line `//system("php5-cgi /var/www/cgi-bin/send_email.php sujet,texte");`, the "alert(xhr.responseText)" displays the printf returns from the c program.

If someone has an idea to help me ... thank you in advance.

Comment: did you tell your webserver that your C app is a cgi app? it might be serving up the raw binary contents of the executable file, instead of executing it.

Comment: yeah I think I did that, how would you do?

Comment: I think  the problem comes from the system () function with php5-cgi
because when replace it with `system("ls");` the "alert(xhr.responseText)" displays the directory contents

Comment: Can i see the php code?

Comment: I do not think the php code to be involved, it's the same result with this simple code : `<?php echo'hello'; ?>`

Comment: What might be happening is the C code reads the CGI request, including the request body, and then the executed PHP tries to do the same from the inherited socket, but simply blocks waiting for input that will never come, since it has already been read by the C program.